# POST http://localhost:7500/api/users/posts 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

So I am trying to save some data into a mongodb data base using axios
I created a form to fill then when i click on save the data must be saved.

this is my try:

```js
import auction1 from '../../Images/auction1.png'
import {useState} from 'react';
import './HomeScreen.css'
import {Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';

const HomeScreen = ()=>{

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(null);
    const [deadline, setDeadLine] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

    const [img, setImg] = useState("");

    const [imgMessage, setImgMessage] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);


    const handleSubmit = async(e)=>{

        e.preventDefault();

        try{
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                }
            }

            const {data} = await axios.post("http://localhost:7500/api/users/posts",
            {name, img, deadline, price, description}, 
            config
            );

            console.log(data);

        }catch(error){
            console.log(error.response.data.message);
        }
    };


    const postDetails = (pic)=>{

        if(!pic){
            return setImgMessage('Please select a picture');
        }

        setImgMessage(null);

        if(pic.type === 'images/jpeg' || pic.type==='image/png'){
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append('file', pic);
            data.append('upload_preset', 'battta');
            data.append('cloud_name', 'ChkounZed');
            fetch("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/ChkounZed/upload", {
                method: 'post',
                body: data
            })
            .then((res)=> res.json())
            .then((data)=> {
                console.log(data);
                setImg(data.url.toString())
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error);
            });
        }else{
            return setImgMessage('Please select a picture');
        }
    };


    
    return(
        <div className="container bg">
            <img src ={auction1} className='landing-image' />
            <div style={{marginLeft:460}}> 
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
                    Create Post
                </Button>
            </div> 
            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Create Post</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <form >
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Post Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"
                                value={name} onChange={(e)=> setName(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Post Images:</label>
                                <input type="file" className="form-control" multiple onChange="readURL(this)" accept="Image/*" 
                                onChange={(e)=> postDetails(e.target.files[0])}/>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <label>Price:</label>
                                <input type="number" className="form-control" placeholder="TND"
                                value={price} onChange={(e)=> setPrice(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label>DeadLine:</label>
                                <input type="datetime-local" className="form-control"
                                value={deadline} onChange={(e)=> setDeadLine(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label>Description:</label>
                                <textarea className="form-control" rows="3"
                                value={description} onChange={(e)=> setDescription(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onClick={handleClose} >
                            Save Post
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onClick={handleClose}>
                            Close
                        </button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </form>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )

};

export default HomeScreen;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

that was my react component and the problem is that i keep getting a message that says the post already exists.

this is my postController from the backend side:

```js
const Post = require("../Models/postModel");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");


const savePost = asyncHandler(async(req,res)=>{

    const {name, deadline, price, description, image} = req.body;
 

    const postExists = await Post.findOne({image});
    
    if(postExists){
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error('Post Already Exists');
    }

    const post = await Post.create({
        name,
        deadline,
        price,
        description,
        image
    });

    if(post){
        res.status(201).json({
            _id: post._id,
            name: post.name, 
            price: post.price, 
            image: post.image,
            deadline: post.deadline,
            description: post.description
        });
    }else{
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error('Error');
    }
});

module.exports = {savePost};
```

I would be so grateful if you can give me hand of this and by the way i wanna make my post unique using the images and still did not know how

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information? Your Post Model. What happens at the DB Collection? Is it empty?
The response of mongodb includes _id why not use findById instead of find({image}).

When u wipe your database and post the first time whats the response of your post to /api/users/posts?

To make some fields unique for the collection you can use unique like below:

```
const PlayerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:{
      type: String,
      unique: true
  }
})
```